# Max_connection in postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, pgbouncer

I have postgres server that is limited on 100 max_connections, and in some moment when is application is in heavy use that limit is reached, so i try to increase that number and when i try to restart postgres, wont start, and in log i got message that can't start because of some of System V IPC parameters(Ubuntu linux). So question is next, is it better to try to change this parameter or it is better to use some of postgres plugin like pgbouncer(i think i read somewhere that pgbouncer can resolve this problem)  or etc... any advice about changing  System V IPC parameters or resolving with some plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not better to bump `max_connection` too much. More connections cost more system resources.

> Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
>   
>   connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).

Please take a look at the relevant wiki article:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections

About the problem of System V IPC, I have no idea. I set `max_connections=2000`(Ubuntu linux, PostgreSQL 9.3), it can restart.

**Update:**
This article introduces some about `Shared Memory and Semaphores` and the methods to set them for some platforms.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC

Comment: It's different for older PostgreSQL versions - 9.2 and older used a lot more system V shared memory because they used it for `shared_buffers` etc; 9.3 only uses a tiny SYSV segment and then uses posix shmem for the rest.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger, I found some articles about `shared memory and semaphores`: 1) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC  
2) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/server-start.html#SERVER-START-FAILURES
3) 9.3 reduces `System V shared memory` requirements, 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-3.html